# implementation of a 2d pendulum

Tags: game-physics

I am implementing a 2d pendulum for rope action in my worm-like game,I initially intended to use the angle formula,namely `angleNow = maxAngle * cos( sqrt(g/length) * t)`,but the question comes to how I handle collision of the man in the rope.Now I am using the classical mechanics,I am calculating the centripetal force at every instant,`centripetal = gravity_constant * cos(speed_angle) + pow(speed,2)/length`.Therefore the man in the rope have two forces upon it,one is gravity and the other one is centripetal,which is changing all the time.I use the formula 
`deltaVelocity = acceleration * (time - this.lastTime)` to calculate the velocity change,that may be the problem because the update of gravity delta and centripetal delta are not consistent.
the problem now is that the length of the rope is always changing,which is not a pendulum and the rope is inclined to go very far to one side and then come back.

BTW,the game is web-based and I am using javascript to implement it,Thank you in advance.
this is the code I used to calculate centripetal:

```
this.magnitude = (Math.pow(character.velocityX,2) + Math.pow(character.velocityY,2))/sprite.length;
            this.angle = Math.atan(character.velocityY/character.velocityX);
            this.delta =  GRAVITY_CONSTANT * Math.cos(this.angle);
            this.magnitude += this.delta;
            character.velocityX += this.magnitude * Math.sin(this.angle) * ((time - this.lastTime) /1000);
            character.velocityY -= this.magnitude * Math.cos(this.angle) * ((time - this.lastTime) /1000);
```